# Non-homotopic cdga maps with same effect on cohomology

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, morita-theory

Let $f, g : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be maps of commutative differential graded algebras. An easy way to tell if they are homotopic is by looking at their effect on cohomology.

1. However, if $f$ and $g$ define the same map on cohomology algebras, are there other common techniques to try and distinguish their homotopy class?
2. If either $\mathcal A$ or $\mathcal B$ is a formal cdga, is it known (or true?) that a map's effect on cohomology completely determines is homotopy class?

Regarding 1:

- The first technique I can think of is trying to compute $f$ and $g$'s effects on Massey products. But are there other standard invariants one can compute?
- All the other techniques I can think of seem a bit extreme. For instance, trying to see if $\mathcal{B}$ defines two inequivalent bimodules over $\mathcal{A}$ when using the action induced by $f$, versus the action induced by $g$. The only way I know of doing this is to try and compute Hochschild cohomology or homology of $\mathcal{A}$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{B}$, which seems also very difficult. Are there easier ways to distinguish the equivalence class of $\mathcal{B}$ as a bimodule?

Comment: Even if both A and B are formal, the homotopy class of a map isn't detected by its effect on cohomology. As an example, let A and B both be the minimal model for $S^3 \times S^3 \times S^5 \times S^6$. You can prove any homotopy from the identity map must actually be constant (so only the identity map is homotopic to the identity map), while you can also construct another map inducing the identity on cohomology. See 12(d) of Felix-Halperin-Thomas.